# Validate complex string input (fixed length pattern)

Tags: regex, validation, input, digits

What is the best way to validate this type of input:

```
1234,4589,7889
```

Only allowed numbers. Each number must contain 4 digits. They are separated by `,`. There can be one or many. Last item does not have a separator.

Answer (score 0):

- Each number must contain 4 digits : `\d{4}`
- They are separated by "," : `\d{4},\d{4}`
- There can be one or many : `(?:\d{4},)+`
- Last item does not have a separator => aka 4 digits followed by any number of comma + 4 digits : `\d{4}(?:,\d{4})*`

`^\d{4}(?:,\d{4})*$` to make sure the pattern cover the start and the end of the string.